# C# WPF tree view extremely slow to populate. Unauthorized access potenial slowdown?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm just doing some playing around with C# WPF applications and I'm trying to merely recreate a tree view of my local directories. It's extremely slow which I think in part is due to the fact that there are access issues with some of the folders.

If I set the path to documents or downloads its instantaneous. If I set it to just Users\ or user\myUsername it just keeps going and going and I catch a bunch of access exceptions. Is it possible to first check if I have access to that directory, say AppData or another user folder? Or is the try catch in the wrong spot.

My code for the relevant populating is below.

```
private static TreeViewItem PopulateNodes(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {

        var directoryNode = new TreeViewItem { Header = directoryInfo.Name };

        try
        {
            foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories())
                directoryNode.Items.Add(PopulateNodes(directory));

            foreach (var file in directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles())
                directoryNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem { Header = file.Name });


            return directoryNode;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex){
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        };

        return directoryNode;

    }
```

Comment: if you are calling this function recursively, then you must limit the depth, otherwise it will be very slow

Comment: Ya I was thinking the recursion might be slow, any better way you'd recommend.

Comment: already told you: limit the depth!

Comment: You can also speed it up by using `Treeview.BeginUpdate()` before adding the data, and `Treeview.EndUpdate()` once you've added it.

Comment: Haven't done much with limiting recursion, but I'll give both these suggestions a try. Thanks.

Comment: If your are working with files, that's fine to add data to treeview dynamically and only from 'current' folder, so you will add data only when user will try open tree's node.
If you want to load all data at once, use task to load data, and when it's build all tree add it to treeview so it could show it, that's much better.